# Azure pipeline condition on vmimage name

Tags: azure-pipelines

How can I *not* try to install `dotnet-ef` for an old `net45` project that needs the old `windows-2019` image to build it.

I tried

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Install dotnet-ef
  condition: ne(variables['Environment.Name'], 'windows-2019')
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install --global dotnet-ef'
```

In the log I see

```
...
##[debug]Task 'Install dotnet-ef' has following condition: 'ne(variables['Environment.Name'], 'windows-2019')'.
##[debug]Parsing expression: <ne(variables['Environment.Name'], 'windows-2019')>
##[debug]ne
##[debug](
##[debug]..variables
##[debug]..[
##[debug]....'Environment.Name'
##[debug]..]
##[debug]..,
##[debug]..'windows-2019'
##[debug])
...
```

But the task attempts to run.

This doesn't work either.

```
- ${{ if ne(parameters.vmImage, 'windows-2019') }}: 
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Install dotnet-ef
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      custom: 'tool'
      arguments: 'install --global dotnet-ef'
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation for predefined variables? `Environment.Name` is *not* going to be the name of the agent pool. In fact, it's not even going to exist outside of a deployment job, which is why it's not resolving to anything for you.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure DevOps Pipeline, the variable: `Environment.Name` is not a predefined variable or system variable. So you can't directly use it. Refer to this doc: [Use predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can use the agent system variable variable:**ImageOS**.

For example:

```
windows-2019 -> ImageOS = win19

windows-2022 -> ImageOS = win22
```

Task condition:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Install dotnet-ef
  condition: ne(variables['ImageOS '], 'win19')
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install --global dotnet-ef'
```